# Prove that sine is surjective under a certain domain and codomain

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

Here's the problem:

Let $f:[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}] \to [-1,1]$ be the map defined as $f(x) = \sin(x)$ for any $x \in I = [-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$. Prove that $f$ is surjective.

---

Proof Attempt:

We know that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and, therefore, is continuous in the given closed interval. We also know that continuous functions map closed intervals to closed intervals.

In particular, the endpoints of $f(I)$ have to be the absolute extrema of $f$. Now, since $f$ is increasing in $I$, it follows that $min(f(I)) = -1$ and $min(f(I)) = 1$. So, $f(I) = [-1,1]$. This proves the desired result.

Does this proof work? If it doesn't, why? How can I fix it?

Comment: I'm still open to my proof being verified. Not particularly sure if it's correct, even taking the discussion below into consideration.

Answer (score 2):

"In particular, the endpoints of f(I) have to be the absolute extrema of f".This is not true, imagine if the interval was $[-\pi, \pi]$. What you do know is $\sin(\pi/2) = 1$ and $\sin(-\pi/2) = -1$. Since $\sin$ is continuous, we have by the mean value theorem that all values between -1 and 1 are hit, hence it is surjective.

Comment: Uh the proof of the fact that continuous functions map closed intervals into closed intervals involves showing the fact that $f(I) = [m,M]$ where $m$ is the absolute minimum of $f$ in the interval and $M$ is the absolute maximum of $f$ in the closed interval. If the interval is $[-\pi,\pi]$, then it's still the case that the endpoints of $f([-\pi,\pi])$ would be -1 and 1, both of which are the absolute extrema of $f$.

Comment: Alos, i haven't gotten to the part where the mean-value theorem is used so i'm afraid i can't use that here and i don't think it's necessary?

Comment: Ah okay. Then you argue again that f obtains the value -1 and 1 and conclude that the image is [-1,1] since this is the only closed interval in the range that contains both those points.

Comment: Yeap but taking into consideration the justification I've given in the comment above, with the proof of the fact that continuous functions map closed intervals to closed intervals, is the proof that I've provided correct?